# How can I check I if KPTI is enabled on Android?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

On a regular Linux system, I would inspect dmesg to see if KPTI is enabled. However, on Android dmesg is disabled unless I root the phone.
Is there a way to check if KPTI is enabled without rooting the phone?